# Exception handling PL SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

My Application has following two procedure which handles the entire transaction.
But when my nested procedure throws an exception the CRUD operation performed in outer procedure could not get roll back. Please help me to re arrange it or how could I write in better way so that I can roll back my transaction.

```
PROCEDURE SP_SEND_CASE_NEXT_LEVEL
(
  p_wfId  IN NUMBER,
  p_assessmentId      IN NUMBER,
  p_prevLevelId       IN NUMBER,
  p_appType           IN NUMBER,
  p_sequenceNumber    IN NUMBER,
  p_subSequenceNumber IN NUMBER,
  p_userCode          IN VARCHAR2,
  p_companyCode       IN VARCHAR2,
  p_camNumber         IN VARCHAR2,
  p_reviewType        IN NUMBER,
  p_unitType          IN NUMBER,
  p_regionCode        IN NUMBER,
  p_caseType          IN VARCHAR2,
  p_isApproved        IN VARCHAR2,
  p_fromUserCode      IN VARCHAR2,
  P_ERRORDETAIL       OUT VARCHAR2
) IS

  V_Newlevelid           NUMBER(8);
  V_NewWfId              NUMBER(8);
  v_StepCompleted        NUMBER(2); 
  v_caseComplete         VARCHAR2(1);
  v_isStepComplete       VARCHAR2(1);
  v_isCompanyPicked      VARCHAR2(1);
  v_subUserInWorkflow    NUMBER(1);
  v_isPresent            NUMBER(1);
  v_inConsistentWorkFlow VARCHAR2(2);
  v_subUserCode          VARCHAR2(8);
  v_errmsg               VARCHAR2(50);
  v_userDP               NUMBER(10, 2);
  v_sql                  VARCHAR2(2000);
  v_sub_seq_no           NUMBER(8);
  v_reversalSequenceNo   NUMBER(4);
  v_reversalAppType      NUMBER(2);
  v_NewCourierId        NUmber(8);
  v_courierCount          NUMBER(1);
  v_revSequenceNo       NUMBER(4);
  v_courierComments VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_required_count  NUMBER(2);
  v_sessionPriority NUMBER(1);
  v_customRequiredCount NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
  p_errorDetail          := 'Failure';
  v_inConsistentWorkFlow := 'N';
  v_reversalAppType      := 0;
  v_revSequenceNo         :=0;
  v_courierComments := '';
  v_customRequiredCount := 0;
  SAVEPOINT Start_Tran;
  BEGIN

    -- update aph_comp_leveldetails for initiator of case
    UPDATE Aph_Comp_Leveldetails
       SET Case_Complete    = 'Y',
           End_Date         = Sysdate,
           Is_Step_Complete = 'Y',
           is_approved      = p_isApproved
     WHERE User_Code = p_userCode
       AND Assessmentid = p_assessmentId
       and levelid = p_prevlevelid;

    -- update Aph_Comp_Header for case status
    UPDATE Aph_Comp_Header
       SET CASE_STATUS_DESC = 'Pending',
       COMP_REVERSE = 'N'           
     WHERE Assessmentid = p_assessmentId;

    -- update MST_TAT_CALC set case end time for previous level user
    UPDATE MST_TAT_CALC
       SET CASE_END_TIME = sysdate,
       RULE_END_TIME = sysdate,
       days = fn_get_days(RULE_START_TIME, sysdate, REASON)
     WHERE User_Code = p_userCode -- TODO : to be removed
       and LEVELID = p_prevLevelId
       AND ASSESSMENTID = p_assessmentId
       and reason <> 'C' and CASE_END_TIME is null;
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SELECT COUNT(CASE_COMPLETE) into v_required_count
    FROM APH_COMP_LEVELDETAILS
    WHERE ASSESSMENTID = p_assessmentid
    AND SEQ_NO         = p_sequenceNumber
    AND APP_TYPE       = p_appType
    and COMP_REVERSE = 'N'
    and COMP_WITHDRAWN = 'N'
    and COMP_REJECTED = 'N';

    SELECT COUNT(CASE_COMPLETE) into v_StepCompleted
    FROM APH_COMP_LEVELDETAILS
    WHERE ASSESSMENTID = p_assessmentid
    AND SEQ_NO         = p_sequenceNumber
    AND APP_TYPE       = p_appType
    AND CASE_COMPLETE  = 'Y'
    and COMP_REVERSE = 'N'
    and COMP_WITHDRAWN = 'N'
    and COMP_REJECTED = 'N';



                            BEGIN
                              -- aph_comp_leveldetails
                              INSERT INTO aph_comp_leveldetails
                                (WF_ID,
                                 ASSESSMENTID,
                                 LEVELID,
                                 User_Code,
                                 Case_Complete,
                                 COMP_FROMUSER,
                                 SEQ_NO,
                                 SUB_SEQ_NO,
                                 COMP_TOUSER,
                                 Start_Date,
                                 IS_STEP_COMPLETE,
                                 Is_Company_Picked,
                                 App_Type,
                                 WORK_FLOW_USER)
                              VALUES
                                (Send.Wf_Id,
                                 p_assessmentId,
                                 V_Newlevelid,
                                 USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code,
                                 'N',
                                 --send.user_id,
                                 P_USERCODE,
                                 Send.Sequence_No,
                                 v_sub_seq_no,
                                 USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code,
                                 Sysdate,
                                 'N',
                                 'N',
                                 Send.App_Type,
                                 Send.user_id);
                            EXCEPTION
                              WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                ROLLBACK;
                                v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into aph_comp_leveldetails as previous level step not completed';
                                RETURN;
                            END;
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            BEGIN
                              -- check if user is alreadily part of workflow.
                              SELECT COUNT(*)
                                INTO v_isPresent
                                FROM aph_wf_user
                               WHERE ASSESSMENTID = P_ASSESSMENTID
                                 and USER_ID = USER_ON_HOLIDAY.USER_CODE
                                 and is_wf_user = 'Y';
                            END;
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            IF v_isPresent = 0 THEN
                              -- if user is not alreadily part of workflow then insert into aph_wf_user.
                              BEGIN
                                -- insert in aph_wf_user
                                INSERT INTO aph_wf_user
                                  (WF_ID,
                                   ASSESSMENTID,
                                   USER_ID,
                                   SEQUENCE_NO,
                                   APP_TYPE,
                                   IS_EDITABLE,
                                   USER_DP,
                                   UNIT_TYPE,
                                   CREATED_BY,
                                   CREATION_DATE)
                                VALUES
                                  (V_NewWfId,
                                   P_ASSESSMENTID,
                                   USER_ON_HOLIDAY.user_code,
                                   Send.Sequence_No,
                                   send.app_type,
                                   'N',
                                   v_userDP,
                                   send.unit_type,
                                   P_USERCODE,
                                   sysdate);
                              EXCEPTION
                                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                  ROLLBACK;
                                  v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into aph_comp_leveldetails as previous level step not completed';
                                  RETURN;
                              END;
                            END IF; -- end of  if v_isPresent = 0
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            BEGIN
                              --mst_tat_calc
                              INSERT INTO mst_tat_calc
                                (ASSESSMENTID,
                                 LEVELID,
                                 COMPANY_CODE,
                                 USER_CODE,
                                 REASON,
                                 CASE_START_TIME,
                                 CASE_END_TIME,
                                 RULE_START_TIME,
                                 RULE_END_TIME,
                                 CAM_NUMBER,
                                 REVIEW_TYPE,
                                 UNIT_TYPE,
                                 REGION_CODE,
                                 LEVELID_COURIER_TO)
                              VALUES
                                (P_ASSESSMENTID,
                                 /*p_prevLevelId,*/
                                 V_NEWLEVELID, 
                                 P_COMPANYCODE,
                                 /*p_userCode,*/
                                 USER_ON_HOLIDAY.user_code,
                                 'C',--This should be value of enum CommonActionEnum.COURIER
                                 sysdate,
                                 null,
                                 sysdate,
                                 null,
                                 p_camNumber,
                                 p_reviewType,
                                 p_unitType,
                                 P_REGIONCODE,
                                 /*V_Newlevelid*/
                                 p_prevLevelId 
                                 );
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              INSERT INTO mst_tat_calc
                                (ASSESSMENTID,
                                 LEVELID,
                                 COMPANY_CODE,
                                 USER_CODE,
                                 REASON,
                                 CASE_START_TIME,
                                 RULE_START_TIME,
                                 CAM_NUMBER,
                                 REVIEW_TYPE,
                                 UNIT_TYPE,
                                 REGION_CODE,
                                 DAYS)
                              VALUES
                                (P_ASSESSMENTID,
                                 V_NEWLEVELID,
                                 p_companyCode,
                                 USER_ON_HOLIDAY.user_code,
                                 'N',--This should be value of enum CommonActionEnum.NORMAL_APPROVAL
                                 sysdate,
                                 fn_get_rule_date(sysdate),
                                 p_camNumber,
                                 p_reviewType,
                                 p_unitType,
                                 p_regionCode,
                                 0);
                            EXCEPTION
                              WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                ROLLBACK;
                                v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into mst_tat_calc as normal approver';
                                RETURN;
                            END;
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            -- Check for if user has any courier
                            BEGIN
                              -- update in aph_user_Courier as courier status sent and sent date
                              SELECT COUNT(1)
                                INTO v_courierCount
                              FROM aph_user_courier
                              WHERE assessmentid = p_assessmentid
                                AND touser         = USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code
                                AND levelid        = p_prevlevelid;

                              if v_courierCount = 0 then
                               begin
                                 Pack_Aph_Getid.Proc_Aph_Getid('APH_USER_COURIER','COURIER_ID', v_NewCourierId); -- generate courier id.
                               end;

                               INSERT
                                INTO APH_USER_COURIER
                                  (
                                    COURIER_ID,
                                    ASSESSMENTID,
                                    LEVELID,
                                    FROMUSER,
                                    TOUSER,
                                    FROMUSER_COMMENTS,
                                    TOUSER_COMMENTS,
                                    FROMCOURIER_STATUS,
                                    TOCOURIER_STATUS,
                                    FROM_DATETIME,
                                    TO_DATETIME,
                                    DOCUMENTRECEIVED,
                                    RECEIVEDDATE
                                  )
                                  --values (v_NewCourierId, p_assessmentid, V_Newlevelid, p_usercode, Send.User_Id, null, null, 'SENT' , null , sysdate , null, null, null);
                                  VALUES
                                  (
                                    v_NewCourierId,
                                    p_assessmentid,
                                    V_Newlevelid,
                                    p_usercode,
                                    USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code,
                                    v_courierComments,
                                    NULL,
                                    'SENT' ,
                                    NULL ,
                                    sysdate ,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL
                                  );
                              else
                                UPDATE aph_user_Courier
                                   SET fromcourier_status = 'SENT',
                                        tocourier_status = null,
                                       FROM_DATETIME      = SYSDATE
                                 WHERE assessmentid = p_assessmentid
                                   AND levelid = p_prevlevelid
                                   --AND touser = Send.User_Id;
                                   AND touser = USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code
                              end if;

                            EXCEPTION
                              WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                ROLLBACK;
                                v_errmsg := 'Unable to update aph_user_Courier';
                                RETURN;
                            END;    

               BEGIN
                               SP_COMMON_INSERTS(p_assessmentId, p_prevLevelId, V_Newlevelid, 'N', 'N',0,'0','N', p_errorDetail)
                             EXCEPTION
                              WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                p_Errordetail := 'Error in common';
                ROLLBACK;
                            END;

                            BEGIN
                              UPDATE APH_WF_USER set IS_EDITABLE = 'N' where USER_ID = Send.User_Id and ASSESSMENTID = p_assessmentId;
                            END;
                        END;
END SP_SEND_CASE_NEXT_LEVEL;

Procedure Sp_Common_Inserts
(
  --p_wfId In Number,
  p_assessmentId In Number,
  p_prevLevelId In Number,
  p_Newlevelid in number,
  p_withdraw in varchar2,
  p_rejected in varchar2,
  p_prevAssessmentId in Number,
  p_borrowerCode in varchar2,
  p_srm_lcr in varchar2,
  p_errorDetail Out Varchar2
) Is

v_wfId Number(8);
V_Errmsg Varchar2(50);
v_initiatorUserCode varchar2(50);
V_SrNo Number(8);

Begin
     -- Savepoint Start_Tran1;

      if p_withdraw = 'N' and p_rejected = 'N' then
      begin
      -- APH_ASSESSMENT_PARAMETER
      INSERT INTO APH_ASSESSMENT_PARAMETER
      (
      SR_NO,
      ASSESSMENTID,
      LEVELID,
      CAM_DATE,
      REVISION_DATE,
      SRM_EXPIRY_DATE,
      PART_PROGRAM,
      PRODUCT_PROGRAM,
      PRODUCT_PROGRM_EXPOSURE,
      PROGRM_PARAMETERS_ADHERED,
      IS_SEPARETE_APPROVER,
      CASH_BACKED_EXPOSURE,
      EXPOSURE_GURANTED,
      CLIMS_ID,
      CAM_LOGIN_DATE,
      BORROWER_RATING,
      RATING_TYPE,
      RATING_FINALISATION_DATE,
      INITIAL_LABELLING_DATE,
      CURRENT_REVIEW_DATE,
      LABEL_REVIEW_TYPE,
      LABEL,
      LAST_CLIENT_CALL_DATE,
      CALLED_ON_DATE,
      INTERFACE_DATE,
      COMP_CODE
      ) SELECT
      SR_NO,
      p_assessmentId,
      p_Newlevelid,
      CAM_DATE,
      REVISION_DATE,
      SRM_EXPIRY_DATE,
      PART_PROGRAM,
      PRODUCT_PROGRAM,
      PRODUCT_PROGRM_EXPOSURE,
      PROGRM_PARAMETERS_ADHERED,
      IS_SEPARETE_APPROVER,
      CASH_BACKED_EXPOSURE,
      EXPOSURE_GURANTED,
      CLIMS_ID,
      CAM_LOGIN_DATE,
      BORROWER_RATING,
      RATING_TYPE,
      RATING_FINALISATION_DATE,
      INITIAL_LABELLING_DATE,
      CURRENT_REVIEW_DATE,
      LABEL_REVIEW_TYPE,
      LABEL,
      LAST_CLIENT_CALL_DATE,
      CALLED_ON_DATE,
      INTERFACE_DATE,
      COMP_CODE
      From APH_ASSESSMENT_PARAMETER
      Where Levelid = p_prevlevelid;
      Exception 
      When No_Data_Found Then
      rollback;
      v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into APH_ADDENDUM_DETAILS as no data found at previous level';
      return;
      end;

      end if;

      IF P_WITHDRAW = 'Y' or P_REJECTED = 'Y' THEN
      --APH_APPRAISAL_DETAILS
      begin
      INSERT INTO APH_APPRAISAL_DETAILS
      (
      ASSESSMENTID,
      COMPANY_CODE,
      CAM_FORMAT_ID,
      FILE_NAME,
      ORDER_ID,
      REPORTS_HTML_CONTENTS,
      SR_NO
      )SELECT
      p_assessmentId,
      COMPANY_CODE,
      CAM_FORMAT_ID,
      FILE_NAME,
      ORDER_ID,
      REPORTS_HTML_CONTENTS,
      SR_NO
      FROM APH_APPRAISAL_DETAILS
      WHERE ASSESSMENTID = P_prevAssessmentId
      AND FILE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT FILE_NAME FROM APH_FTL_DETAILS WHERE FTL_ID IN(29,30,31));
      Exception 
      When No_Data_Found Then
      rollback;
      v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into APH_BORROWER_DETAILS as no data found at previous level';
      Return;
      End;
      END IF;

  p_Errordetail:='SUCCESS';

     Exception
       When Others Then
         Rollback;
           p_Errordetail :=v_errmsg;

End Sp_Common_Inserts;
```

Please let me know how to handle exception in above two procedures if nested procedure sp_common_insert throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `RETURN`, use `RAISE` instead. That way, the error encountered in your sub blocks will also trigger the exception that sets the value of `p_Errordetail` in your main block. Another thing is that you don't have an EXCEPTION block in SP_SEND_CASE_NEXT_LEVEL procedure's main block. Here's a revision of your code:

```
  PROCEDURE SP_SEND_CASE_NEXT_LEVEL
  (
    p_wfId  IN NUMBER,
    p_assessmentId      IN NUMBER,
    p_prevLevelId       IN NUMBER,
    p_appType           IN NUMBER,
    p_sequenceNumber    IN NUMBER,
    p_subSequenceNumber IN NUMBER,
    p_userCode          IN VARCHAR2,
    p_companyCode       IN VARCHAR2,
    p_camNumber         IN VARCHAR2,
    p_reviewType        IN NUMBER,
    p_unitType          IN NUMBER,
    p_regionCode        IN NUMBER,
    p_caseType          IN VARCHAR2,
    p_isApproved        IN VARCHAR2,
    p_fromUserCode      IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ERRORDETAIL       OUT VARCHAR2
  ) IS

    V_Newlevelid           NUMBER(8);
    V_NewWfId              NUMBER(8);
    v_StepCompleted        NUMBER(2); 
    v_caseComplete         VARCHAR2(1);
    v_isStepComplete       VARCHAR2(1);
    v_isCompanyPicked      VARCHAR2(1);
    v_subUserInWorkflow    NUMBER(1);
    v_isPresent            NUMBER(1);
    v_inConsistentWorkFlow VARCHAR2(2);
    v_subUserCode          VARCHAR2(8);
    v_errmsg               VARCHAR2(50);
    v_userDP               NUMBER(10, 2);
    v_sql                  VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_sub_seq_no           NUMBER(8);
    v_reversalSequenceNo   NUMBER(4);
    v_reversalAppType      NUMBER(2);
    v_NewCourierId        NUmber(8);
    v_courierCount          NUMBER(1);
    v_revSequenceNo       NUMBER(4);
    v_courierComments VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_required_count  NUMBER(2);
    v_sessionPriority NUMBER(1);
    v_customRequiredCount NUMBER(1);
  BEGIN
    p_errorDetail          := 'Failure';
    v_inConsistentWorkFlow := 'N';
    v_reversalAppType      := 0;
    v_revSequenceNo         :=0;
    v_courierComments := '';
    v_customRequiredCount := 0;
    SAVEPOINT Start_Tran;
    BEGIN

      -- update aph_comp_leveldetails for initiator of case
      UPDATE Aph_Comp_Leveldetails
         SET Case_Complete    = 'Y',
             End_Date         = Sysdate,
             Is_Step_Complete = 'Y',
             is_approved      = p_isApproved
       WHERE User_Code = p_userCode
         AND Assessmentid = p_assessmentId
         and levelid = p_prevlevelid;

      -- update Aph_Comp_Header for case status
      UPDATE Aph_Comp_Header
         SET CASE_STATUS_DESC = 'Pending',
         COMP_REVERSE = 'N'           
       WHERE Assessmentid = p_assessmentId;

      -- update MST_TAT_CALC set case end time for previous level user
      UPDATE MST_TAT_CALC
         SET CASE_END_TIME = sysdate,
         RULE_END_TIME = sysdate,
         days = fn_get_days(RULE_START_TIME, sysdate, REASON)
       WHERE User_Code = p_userCode -- TODO : to be removed
         and LEVELID = p_prevLevelId
         AND ASSESSMENTID = p_assessmentId
         and reason <> 'C' and CASE_END_TIME is null;
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      SELECT COUNT(CASE_COMPLETE) into v_required_count
      FROM APH_COMP_LEVELDETAILS
      WHERE ASSESSMENTID = p_assessmentid
      AND SEQ_NO         = p_sequenceNumber
      AND APP_TYPE       = p_appType
      and COMP_REVERSE = 'N'
      and COMP_WITHDRAWN = 'N'
      and COMP_REJECTED = 'N';

      SELECT COUNT(CASE_COMPLETE) into v_StepCompleted
      FROM APH_COMP_LEVELDETAILS
      WHERE ASSESSMENTID = p_assessmentid
      AND SEQ_NO         = p_sequenceNumber
      AND APP_TYPE       = p_appType
      AND CASE_COMPLETE  = 'Y'
      and COMP_REVERSE = 'N'
      and COMP_WITHDRAWN = 'N'
      and COMP_REJECTED = 'N';



                              BEGIN
                                -- aph_comp_leveldetails
                                INSERT INTO aph_comp_leveldetails
                                  (WF_ID,
                                   ASSESSMENTID,
                                   LEVELID,
                                   User_Code,
                                   Case_Complete,
                                   COMP_FROMUSER,
                                   SEQ_NO,
                                   SUB_SEQ_NO,
                                   COMP_TOUSER,
                                   Start_Date,
                                   IS_STEP_COMPLETE,
                                   Is_Company_Picked,
                                   App_Type,
                                   WORK_FLOW_USER)
                                VALUES
                                  (Send.Wf_Id,
                                   p_assessmentId,
                                   V_Newlevelid,
                                   USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code,
                                   'N',
                                   --send.user_id,
                                   P_USERCODE,
                                   Send.Sequence_No,
                                   v_sub_seq_no,
                                   USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code,
                                   Sysdate,
                                   'N',
                                   'N',
                                   Send.App_Type,
                                   Send.user_id);
                              EXCEPTION
                                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                  ROLLBACK;
                                  v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into aph_comp_leveldetails as previous level step not completed';
                                  RAISE;
                              END;
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              BEGIN
                                -- check if user is alreadily part of workflow.
                                SELECT COUNT(*)
                                  INTO v_isPresent
                                  FROM aph_wf_user
                                 WHERE ASSESSMENTID = P_ASSESSMENTID
                                   and USER_ID = USER_ON_HOLIDAY.USER_CODE
                                   and is_wf_user = 'Y';
                              END;
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              IF v_isPresent = 0 THEN
                                -- if user is not alreadily part of workflow then insert into aph_wf_user.
                                BEGIN
                                  -- insert in aph_wf_user
                                  INSERT INTO aph_wf_user
                                    (WF_ID,
                                     ASSESSMENTID,
                                     USER_ID,
                                     SEQUENCE_NO,
                                     APP_TYPE,
                                     IS_EDITABLE,
                                     USER_DP,
                                     UNIT_TYPE,
                                     CREATED_BY,
                                     CREATION_DATE)
                                  VALUES
                                    (V_NewWfId,
                                     P_ASSESSMENTID,
                                     USER_ON_HOLIDAY.user_code,
                                     Send.Sequence_No,
                                     send.app_type,
                                     'N',
                                     v_userDP,
                                     send.unit_type,
                                     P_USERCODE,
                                     sysdate);
                                EXCEPTION
                                  WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                    ROLLBACK;
                                    v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into aph_comp_leveldetails as previous level step not completed';
                                    RAISE;
                                END;
                              END IF; -- end of  if v_isPresent = 0
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              BEGIN
                                --mst_tat_calc
                                INSERT INTO mst_tat_calc
                                  (ASSESSMENTID,
                                   LEVELID,
                                   COMPANY_CODE,
                                   USER_CODE,
                                   REASON,
                                   CASE_START_TIME,
                                   CASE_END_TIME,
                                   RULE_START_TIME,
                                   RULE_END_TIME,
                                   CAM_NUMBER,
                                   REVIEW_TYPE,
                                   UNIT_TYPE,
                                   REGION_CODE,
                                   LEVELID_COURIER_TO)
                                VALUES
                                  (P_ASSESSMENTID,
                                   /*p_prevLevelId,*/
                                   V_NEWLEVELID, 
                                   P_COMPANYCODE,
                                   /*p_userCode,*/
                                   USER_ON_HOLIDAY.user_code,
                                   'C',--This should be value of enum CommonActionEnum.COURIER
                                   sysdate,
                                   null,
                                   sysdate,
                                   null,
                                   p_camNumber,
                                   p_reviewType,
                                   p_unitType,
                                   P_REGIONCODE,
                                   /*V_Newlevelid*/
                                   p_prevLevelId 
                                   );
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                INSERT INTO mst_tat_calc
                                  (ASSESSMENTID,
                                   LEVELID,
                                   COMPANY_CODE,
                                   USER_CODE,
                                   REASON,
                                   CASE_START_TIME,
                                   RULE_START_TIME,
                                   CAM_NUMBER,
                                   REVIEW_TYPE,
                                   UNIT_TYPE,
                                   REGION_CODE,
                                   DAYS)
                                VALUES
                                  (P_ASSESSMENTID,
                                   V_NEWLEVELID,
                                   p_companyCode,
                                   USER_ON_HOLIDAY.user_code,
                                   'N',--This should be value of enum CommonActionEnum.NORMAL_APPROVAL
                                   sysdate,
                                   fn_get_rule_date(sysdate),
                                   p_camNumber,
                                   p_reviewType,
                                   p_unitType,
                                   p_regionCode,
                                   0);
                              EXCEPTION
                                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                  ROLLBACK;
                                  v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into mst_tat_calc as normal approver';
                                  RAISE;
                              END;
      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              -- Check for if user has any courier
                              BEGIN
                                -- update in aph_user_Courier as courier status sent and sent date
                                SELECT COUNT(1)
                                  INTO v_courierCount
                                FROM aph_user_courier
                                WHERE assessmentid = p_assessmentid
                                  AND touser         = USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code
                                  AND levelid        = p_prevlevelid;

                                if v_courierCount = 0 then
                                 begin
                                   Pack_Aph_Getid.Proc_Aph_Getid('APH_USER_COURIER','COURIER_ID', v_NewCourierId); -- generate courier id.
                                 end;

                                 INSERT
                                  INTO APH_USER_COURIER
                                    (
                                      COURIER_ID,
                                      ASSESSMENTID,
                                      LEVELID,
                                      FROMUSER,
                                      TOUSER,
                                      FROMUSER_COMMENTS,
                                      TOUSER_COMMENTS,
                                      FROMCOURIER_STATUS,
                                      TOCOURIER_STATUS,
                                      FROM_DATETIME,
                                      TO_DATETIME,
                                      DOCUMENTRECEIVED,
                                      RECEIVEDDATE
                                    )
                                    --values (v_NewCourierId, p_assessmentid, V_Newlevelid, p_usercode, Send.User_Id, null, null, 'SENT' , null , sysdate , null, null, null);
                                    VALUES
                                    (
                                      v_NewCourierId,
                                      p_assessmentid,
                                      V_Newlevelid,
                                      p_usercode,
                                      USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code,
                                      v_courierComments,
                                      NULL,
                                      'SENT' ,
                                      NULL ,
                                      sysdate ,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL
                                    );
                                else
                                  UPDATE aph_user_Courier
                                     SET fromcourier_status = 'SENT',
                                          tocourier_status = null,
                                         FROM_DATETIME      = SYSDATE
                                   WHERE assessmentid = p_assessmentid
                                     AND levelid = p_prevlevelid
                                     --AND touser = Send.User_Id;
                                     AND touser = USER_ON_HOLIDAY.User_code
                                end if;

                              EXCEPTION
                                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                  ROLLBACK;
                                  v_errmsg := 'Unable to update aph_user_Courier';
                                  RAISE;
                              END;    

                 BEGIN
                                 SP_COMMON_INSERTS(p_assessmentId, p_prevLevelId, V_Newlevelid, 'N', 'N',0,'0','N', p_errorDetail)
                               EXCEPTION
                                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                                  p_Errordetail := 'Error in common';
                  ROLLBACK;
                              END;

                              BEGIN
                                UPDATE APH_WF_USER set IS_EDITABLE = 'N' where USER_ID = Send.User_Id and ASSESSMENTID = p_assessmentId;
                              END;
                          END;
  Exception
         When Others Then
           Rollback;
             p_Errordetail :=v_errmsg;
  END SP_SEND_CASE_NEXT_LEVEL;








  Procedure Sp_Common_Inserts
  (
    --p_wfId In Number,
    p_assessmentId In Number,
    p_prevLevelId In Number,
    p_Newlevelid in number,
    p_withdraw in varchar2,
    p_rejected in varchar2,
    p_prevAssessmentId in Number,
    p_borrowerCode in varchar2,
    p_srm_lcr in varchar2,
    p_errorDetail Out Varchar2
  ) Is

  v_wfId Number(8);
  V_Errmsg Varchar2(50);
  v_initiatorUserCode varchar2(50);
  V_SrNo Number(8);

  Begin
       -- Savepoint Start_Tran1;

        if p_withdraw = 'N' and p_rejected = 'N' then
        begin
        -- APH_ASSESSMENT_PARAMETER
        INSERT INTO APH_ASSESSMENT_PARAMETER
        (
        SR_NO,
        ASSESSMENTID,
        LEVELID,
        CAM_DATE,
        REVISION_DATE,
        SRM_EXPIRY_DATE,
        PART_PROGRAM,
        PRODUCT_PROGRAM,
        PRODUCT_PROGRM_EXPOSURE,
        PROGRM_PARAMETERS_ADHERED,
        IS_SEPARETE_APPROVER,
        CASH_BACKED_EXPOSURE,
        EXPOSURE_GURANTED,
        CLIMS_ID,
        CAM_LOGIN_DATE,
        BORROWER_RATING,
        RATING_TYPE,
        RATING_FINALISATION_DATE,
        INITIAL_LABELLING_DATE,
        CURRENT_REVIEW_DATE,
        LABEL_REVIEW_TYPE,
        LABEL,
        LAST_CLIENT_CALL_DATE,
        CALLED_ON_DATE,
        INTERFACE_DATE,
        COMP_CODE
        ) SELECT
        SR_NO,
        p_assessmentId,
        p_Newlevelid,
        CAM_DATE,
        REVISION_DATE,
        SRM_EXPIRY_DATE,
        PART_PROGRAM,
        PRODUCT_PROGRAM,
        PRODUCT_PROGRM_EXPOSURE,
        PROGRM_PARAMETERS_ADHERED,
        IS_SEPARETE_APPROVER,
        CASH_BACKED_EXPOSURE,
        EXPOSURE_GURANTED,
        CLIMS_ID,
        CAM_LOGIN_DATE,
        BORROWER_RATING,
        RATING_TYPE,
        RATING_FINALISATION_DATE,
        INITIAL_LABELLING_DATE,
        CURRENT_REVIEW_DATE,
        LABEL_REVIEW_TYPE,
        LABEL,
        LAST_CLIENT_CALL_DATE,
        CALLED_ON_DATE,
        INTERFACE_DATE,
        COMP_CODE
        From APH_ASSESSMENT_PARAMETER
        Where Levelid = p_prevlevelid;
        Exception 
        When No_Data_Found Then
        rollback;
        v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into APH_ADDENDUM_DETAILS as no data found at previous level';
        RAISE;
        end;

        end if;

        IF P_WITHDRAW = 'Y' or P_REJECTED = 'Y' THEN
        --APH_APPRAISAL_DETAILS
        begin
        INSERT INTO APH_APPRAISAL_DETAILS
        (
        ASSESSMENTID,
        COMPANY_CODE,
        CAM_FORMAT_ID,
        FILE_NAME,
        ORDER_ID,
        REPORTS_HTML_CONTENTS,
        SR_NO
        )SELECT
        p_assessmentId,
        COMPANY_CODE,
        CAM_FORMAT_ID,
        FILE_NAME,
        ORDER_ID,
        REPORTS_HTML_CONTENTS,
        SR_NO
        FROM APH_APPRAISAL_DETAILS
        WHERE ASSESSMENTID = P_prevAssessmentId
        AND FILE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT FILE_NAME FROM APH_FTL_DETAILS WHERE FTL_ID IN(29,30,31));
        Exception 
        When No_Data_Found Then
        rollback;
        v_errmsg := 'Unable to insert into APH_BORROWER_DETAILS as no data found at previous level';
        RAISE;
        End;
        END IF;

    p_Errordetail:='SUCCESS';

       Exception
         When Others Then
           Rollback;
             p_Errordetail :=v_errmsg;

  End Sp_Common_Inserts;
```

Comment: But If I replace return with raise will that flow get halted.

Comment: I see.. put it back to `RETURN`.Since your'e just setting the value of p_Errordetail  in your exception section, why not set the p_Errordetail directly instead of setting it first to v_errmsg.

Comment: If I use raise and return both then? Because I don't want to execute next line of code if there is any exception.

Comment: Means ? Do I write return first and then raise. correct

Comment: Tried using RAISE but not useful. I am not able to rollback insert update executed before calling nested procedure.